# Functional/Immutable Data Structures for the JVM?

Tags: java, data-structures, functional-programming, jvm

Does anyone know of a Java/JVM data structure library providing functional (a.k.a. immutable, or "persistent" in the functional sense) equivalents of the familiar Java data structures?

By "functional" I mean that the objects themselves are immutable, while modifications to those objects return new objects sharing the same internals as the parent object where appropriate (for efficiency in both time and space; a naïve implementation could just copy the whole thing on every write).

Much like Java's concurrency libraries, this doesn't seem like something I can or should implement myself, so it would be nice to have a functional data structure library I can use in the JVM.

Answer (score 14):

Clojure's immutable and persistent data structures have been extracted as a Java library. You can find them at http://github.com/krukow/clj-ds. These data structures are not dependent on the Clojure runtime and hence can be used without the `clojure.jar` in your application's classpath. They have been generified to work smoothly with Java code.

Please make a note that working with these immutable data structures may not be idiomatic in Java.

The github page does not have a jar for download. You will have to checkout the source and build the jar yourself.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great idea, except the code hasn't been maintained for 5 years. Of course, this answer is 9 years old.

Answer (score 7):

Try [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/).  It contains immutable maps, sets, lists, and trees.  However, this library is much more than just a collection of immutable data structures!

Answer (score 6):

Functional and immutable are core properties of most of the Scala collection libraries. Scala compiles to the JVM and interoperates well with Java. The Scala syntax is also much closer to Java than something like Clojure (Lisp syntax).

Here's the intro page to the Scala collection API.
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Scala. It is a convoluted & baroque language not binary compatible with different versions of itself.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), it has immutable map, list, set. It also has some utilities to support immutable collection that instead modifying the underlying object, returns a new object.

Comment: Guava is excellent, but its immutable data structures are not "functional": mutating operations throw `UnsupportedOperationException`, rather than somehow returning an updated copy. The latter would require a different API entirely. Note that this isn't a criticism of Guava; the developers simply regard API compatibility with the standard Java collections as more important than supporting functional idioms.

Answer (score 2):

I can understand why the concurrency classes are difficult to write: it's very easy to get difficult-to-see bugs there.

Java has a nice way to avoid such bugs when writing immutable `Collection` classes: each kind of `Collection` has [a method similar to `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableSet(someSet)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet%28java.util.Set%29), which will give you a wrapper that lets you see the underlying `Collection` but blocks all mutation methods. It's only a wrapper, though: you can still change the underlying `Collection` if you keep a reference to it lying around, so don't do that. Also, immediately clone and wrap any `Collection`s that come from outside your control, since the programmers who handed them to you might modify them later, mutating your nice immutable data.

---

If you want to make a library to handle all these pedantic precautions for you, it's time-consuming but not that hard. To save you time, I've included an example of a minimally-optimized `FunctionalHashSet` with all necessary mutation prevention.

I made an abstract superclass by going down the API listing for `Set` (not forgetting `toString`). For nonmutating methods, I simply pass them on to the underlying `Set`. For mutating methods, I throw `UnsupportedOperationException` and provide alternative functional-style methods.

Here's that abstract class, `FunctionalSet` :

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public abstract class FunctionalSet<E> implements Set<E> {
  // final to prevent mutations through reassignment.
  protected final Set<E> set;

  // private to prevent any use of the default constructor.
  private   FunctionalSet()
    { this.set = null; }
  // unmodifiableSet to prevent mutations through Iterator and in subclasses.
  protected FunctionalSet(final Set<E> set)
    { this.set = Collections.unmodifiableSet(set); }

  public abstract FunctionalSet<E> clone();
  public abstract FunctionalSet<E> fAdd(final E element);
  public abstract FunctionalSet<E> fAddAll(final Collection<? extends E> elements);
  public abstract FunctionalSet<E> fRemove(final Object element);
  public abstract FunctionalSet<E> fRemoveAll(final Collection<?> elements);
  public abstract FunctionalSet<E> fRetainAll(final Collection<?> elements);

  protected abstract FunctionalSet<E> newFSet(final Set<E> newSet);
  protected abstract Set<E> newSet();
  protected abstract Set<E> cloneSet();

  protected final FunctionalSet<E> __fAdd(final E element) {
    if (set.contains(element)) return this;
    final Set<E> newSet = cloneSet();
    newSet.add(element);
    return newFSet(newSet);
  }

  protected final FunctionalSet<E> __fAddAll(final Collection<? extends E> elements) {
    if (set.containsAll(elements)) return this;
    final Set<E> newSet = cloneSet();
    newSet.addAll(elements);
    return newFSet(newSet);
  }

  protected final FunctionalSet<E> __fRemove(final Object element) {
    if (!set.contains(element)) return this;
    final Set<E> newSet = cloneSet();
    newSet.remove(element);
    return newFSet(newSet);
  }

  protected final Set<E> __fRemoveAll(final Collection<?> elements) {
    boolean hasNone = true;
    for (final Object element : elements) {
      if (set.contains(element)) {
        hasNone = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (hasNone) return this;
    final Set<E> newSet = cloneSet();
    newSet.removeAll(elements);
    return newFSet(newSet);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  protected final Set<E> __fRetainAll(final Collection<?> rawElements) {
    final Set elements = rawElements instanceof Set ? (Set) rawElements : new HashSet(rawElements);
    // If set is a subset of elements, we don't remove any of the elements.
    if (set.size() <= elements.size() && elements.containsAll(set)) return this;
    final Set<E> newSet = newSet();
    for (final E element : set) {
      if (elements.contains(element)) newSet.add(element);
    }
    return newFSet(newSet);
  }

  private final UnsupportedOperationException unsupported(final String call, final String goodCall) {
    return new UnsupportedOperationException(
      String.format(this.getClass().getName() + "s are immutable.  Use %s instead of %s.", goodCall, call)
    );
  }

  public final boolean add(final E element)
    { throw unsupported("add", "fAdd"); }
  public final boolean addAll(final Collection<? extends E> elements)
    { throw unsupported("addAll", "fAddAll"); }
  public final void clear()
    { throw unsupported("clear", "new " + this.getClass().getName() + "()"); }
  public final boolean remove(final Object element)
    { throw unsupported("remove", "fRemove"); }
  public final boolean removeAll(final Collection<?> elements)
    { throw unsupported("removeAll", "fRemoveAll"); }
  public final boolean retainAll(final Collection<?> elements)
    { throw unsupported("retainAll", "fRetainAll"); }

  public final boolean contains(final Object element)
    { return set.contains(element); }
  public final boolean containsAll(final Collection<?> elements)
    { return set.containsAll(elements); }
  public final boolean equals(final Object object)
    { return set.equals(object); }
  public final int hashCode()
    { return set.hashCode(); }
  public final boolean isEmpty()
    { return set.isEmpty(); }
  public final Iterator<E> iterator()
    { return set.iterator(); }
  public final int size()
    { return set.size(); }
  public final Object[] toArray()
    { return set.toArray(); }
  public final <E> E[] toArray(final E[] irrelevant)
    { return set.toArray(irrelevant); }
  public final String toString()
    { return set.toString(); }
}
```

In the implementation, there's very little left to do. I supply a few constructors and utility methods and simply use the default implementations of all the mutating methods.

Here's an implementation, `FunctionalHashSet`. :

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public final class FunctionalHashSet<E> extends FunctionalSet<E> implements Cloneable {
  public static final FunctionalHashSet EMPTY = new FunctionalHashSet();

  public FunctionalHashSet()
    { super(new HashSet<E>()); }
  public FunctionalHashSet(final HashSet<E> set)
    { this(set, true); }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private FunctionalHashSet(final HashSet<E> set, final boolean clone)
    { super(clone ? (HashSet<E>) set.clone() : set); }
  public FunctionalHashSet(final Collection<E> elements)
    { this(new HashSet<E>(elements)); }

  protected FunctionalHashSet<E> newFSet(final Set<E> newSet)
    { return new FunctionalHashSet<E>((HashSet<E>) newSet, false); }
  protected HashSet<E> newSet()
    { return new HashSet<E>(); }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  protected HashSet<E> cloneSet()
    { return new HashSet<E>(set); }

  public FunctionalHashSet<E> clone()
    { return this; }
  public FunctionalHashSet<E> fAdd(final E element)
    { return (FunctionalHashSet<E>) __fAdd(element); }
  public FunctionalHashSet<E> fAddAll(final Collection<? extends E> elements)
    { return (FunctionalHashSet<E>) __fAddAll(elements); }
  public FunctionalHashSet<E> fRemove(final Object element)
    { return (FunctionalHashSet<E>) __fRemove(element); }
  public FunctionalHashSet<E> fRemoveAll(final Collection<?> elements)
    { return (FunctionalHashSet<E>) __fRemoveAll(elements); }
  public FunctionalHashSet<E> fRetainAll(final Collection<?> elements)
    { return (FunctionalHashSet<E>) __fRetainAll(elements); }
}
```

A few notes :

- In every single functional mutation method, I check whether there will actually be any changes. If not, I just return the exact same `FunctionalSet`.

  In `clone`, I just return the exact same `FunctionalSet`

  Running `set` through `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableSet` and declaring it `final` prevents two sources of mutation: users can't mutate through the `Iterator` and implementors can't accidentally mutate in their implementations.

You can take this and modify it a bit to support other `Collection`s.

Comment: This answer addresses immutability, but misses one of the main benefits of persistent data structures: maximizing sharing of common substructure between instances.

Answer (score 1):

Java collections are perhaps not as immutable as you would like, even when you apply `Collections.immutable()`

[pure4j](https://github.com/robmoffat/pure4j) provides modified versions of Clojure persistent collections (including generics, for example) and also compile-time immutability checking of your objects, giving you some guarantees that collections cannot change.

Cornelius Mund's project, https://github.com/cornim/ClojureCollections also provides the clojure collections, without the element immutability guarantees, if that is what you need.