# Difference on concatenation for immutable list between java Guava and Scala

Tags: java, scala, immutable-collections

I am trying spark with java and I get stuck by the immutable collections in java.

As I understand in Scala when two immutable lists are combined, no deep copy happens. However the available immutable list in java, like guava, does the defensive copy. (correct me if I am wrong)

So simply my questions are:

1. Is there some Java immutable list which has the same behavior as
   scala immutable list ?
2. If the answer of the first question is NO, what's the
   general(standard) way to use scala immutable collection in java code
   ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Guava collections do not copy all the data when modified. Their implementation is similar to what Scala does.

Comment: Hi Dima, in order to do something like newList = oldList.append(a), I think Guava immutable list will copy all data from oldList and a to the newList, is n't it true ? Or under what conditions could Guava avoid the defensive copy ? Thanks

Comment: No, it's not true. Like I said, guava's collections implementation is similar to that in scala.

Comment: @Dima, what? It's absolutely true, and it's not similar to Scala's implementation. What gave you that impression?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839870

Comment: @LouisWasserman read this: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained
What gave_you_ the impression? :)

Comment: @Dima, I wrote that page, and a large chunk of Guava's collections.  I'm not sure what part of it you have in mind suggesting that it supports efficient modification like you claim.

Comment: @LouisWasserman good for you ;)

Comment: @Dima, if you can point to the specific part of that page that suggests Guava's immutable collections support efficient persistent mutation like you're mentioning, we can fix it to avoid giving that impression.

Comment: @LouisWasserman well, it was this phrase: "It is useful to remember that ImmutableXXX.copyOf attempts to avoid copying the data when it is safe to do so -- the exact details are unspecified, but the implementation is typically "smart". But, upon further inspection, it turns out that the "smartness" it is referring to is just not making extra immutable copies. I stand corrected.

Comment: I tried Immutable.copyOf() and Builder.add(), it doesn't make any copies. And then I checked the source code about Guava in Github, at least for ImmutableList, Builder.add().build() does only copy the reference, no defensive copy happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala Lists is a so-called persistent collection with the persistent referring to the fact, that no defensive copying happens. If you google for `Java persistent collection` you should find several links to get you started. In addition to that, there are a number of libraries that aim to bring the essence of functional programming to Java. As persistent collections are inherently functional, those frameworks often include their own collections implementation. The two libraries I've worked with and can recommend are [Javaslang](http://javaslang.com/) and [Functional Java](http://www.functionaljava.org/) but there are more out there than these two (e.g. [pccollections](http://pcollections.org/), [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL#orgjooqlambdaseq), …).

As for using Scala collections from Java, I've always found this to be somewhat awkward. I would suggest to write a Scala class/object, that gives you easy (as from-Java-easy) access to the `scala.collection.JavaConverters`, so that you can expose your `scala.collection.immutable.List` as a `java.util.List` and work with that interface.